# Error regarding aggregate functions or the group by clause in a FOR XML Path query

Tags: sql-server

Several answers have been give on this area but I would to understand how to solve this issue when it's part of a FOR XML Path.

I would like to concatenate all the discrepancies based on the RegionID. I use group by only on the regionID, but I receive an error saying that discrepancy.description needs to be part of an aggregate (using something like MAX skews my data) and including discrepancy.description in the group by clause also is not accurate.

<<< The whole query has been added for further clarification>>>

```
select top 100
lpr.RegionID,
lpr.Region, 
Max(la.LeftOffWt),
isnull(stuff((select distinct ','+coalesce(discrepancy.description,'NA')
                 from disConsignment as discrepancy
                     inner join whsHeader as wh
                         on wh.WhsHeaderID = discrepancy.WhsHeaderID
                     inner join whsConsignment as wc
                         on wc.whsHeaderID = wh.WhsHeaderID
                     inner join cgtConsignment as c
                         on c.[Consignment Reference] = wc.ConsignmentReference
                     inner join movMovement as m
                         on m.MovementID = wh.RunMovID
                     inner join dbo.genAddress as ga
                         on ga.AddressID = c.Consignor
                     inner join dbo.lstPostcode as lp
                         on lp.Postcode = ga.PostcodePrefix
                     inner join dbo.lstPostcodeRegion as lpr
                         on lpr.RegionID = lp.RegionID
                            and c.Cancelled = 0
                            and discrepancy.WhsHeaderID = wc.whsHeaderID
                 where wc.whsHeaderID = wh.whsHeaderID
                       and wc.StatusCode = 'NL'
                       and wh.ArrDepDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
                       and lpr.RegionID = max (lprdiscrepancy.RegionID)
                 for xml path('')
                ),1,1,''),'') as [Not Collected]
   from movmovement m 
  inner join whsHeader wh on wh.RunMovID = m.MovementID
  Inner join whsConsignment wc on wc.whsHeaderID = wh.WhsHeaderID
  inner join cgtConsignment c on c.[Consignment Reference] = wc.ConsignmentReference
  INNER JOIN dbo.genAddress ga ON ga.AddressID = c.Consignor
  INNER JOIN dbo.lstPostcode lp ON lp.Postcode = ga.PostcodePrefix
  INNER JOIN dbo.lstPostcodeRegion lpr ON lpr.RegionID = lp.RegionID
  inner join disConsignment dc on dc.ConsignmentRef = c.[Consignment Reference]
  Left join (SELECT lpr.RegionID, discrepancy.Description
                   FROM  disConsignment discrepancy
                   inner join whsHeader wh on wh.WhsHeaderID = discrepancy.WhsHeaderID
                   inner join whsConsignment wc on wc.whsHeaderID = wh.WhsHeaderID
                    inner join cgtConsignment c on c.[Consignment Reference] = wc.ConsignmentReference
                    INNER JOIN dbo.genAddress ga ON ga.AddressID = c.Consignor
                    INNER JOIN dbo.lstPostcode lp ON lp.Postcode = ga.PostcodePrefix
                    INNER JOIN lstPostcodeRegion lpr ON lpr.RegionID = lp.RegionID
                            AND c.Cancelled = 0
                            AND discrepancy.WhsHeaderID = wc.whsHeaderID
                  WHERE    wc.whsHeaderID = wh.whsHeaderID
                            AND wc.StatusCode IN ( 'NL' ) 
                            AND lpr.RegionID = lp.RegionID
                            AND wh.ArrDepDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
                            ) lprdiscrepancy on lprdiscrepancy.RegionID = lpr.RegionID
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT lpr.RegionID,
                        SUM(c.[Chargeable Weight]) AS LeftOffWt
                FROM    dbo.whsConsignment wc
                        INNER JOIN whsHeader wh on wh.WhsHeaderID = wc.whsHeaderID
                        INNER JOIN dbo.cgtConsignment c ON c.[Consignment Reference] = wc.ConsignmentReference
                        INNER JOIN dbo.genAddress ga ON ga.AddressID = c.Consignor
                        INNER JOIN dbo.lstPostcode lp ON lp.Postcode = ga.PostcodePrefix
                        INNER JOIN dbo.lstPostcodeRegion lpr ON lpr.RegionID = lp.RegionID
                                                          AND c.Cancelled = 0
                WHERE   StatusCode IN ( 'NL' ) and wh.ArrDepDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
                GROUP BY lpr.RegionID
              ) la ON la.RegionID = lp.RegionID

                      group by lpr.regionID, lpr.Region

                      ORDER BY lpr.RegionID
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the query?  You don't need the group by, but you do need to reference the main query (saying lpr.RegionID = outerquery.RegionID)

Comment: @tompreston hi tom, the entire has been added for further clarification

Comment: iamdave has written a decent answer on this, I could put something up, but it would be very similar to his response.  Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the data fed to the `for xml` part of your script is in a sub-query, it is run for each row that is returned in your main query.  Because it is run for each row, you can reference these values in your sub-select.  This means that you don't need your `group by` and should instead change it to just reference the `RegionID` column in your main query:

```
select isnull(stuff((select distinct
                            ','+coalesce(discrepancy.description,'NA')
                     from disConsignment as discrepancy
                         inner join whsHeader as wh
                             on wh.WhsHeaderID = discrepancy.WhsHeaderID
                         inner join whsConsignment as wc
                             on wc.whsHeaderID = wh.WhsHeaderID
                         inner join cgtConsignment as c
                             on c.[Consignment Reference] = wc.ConsignmentReference
                         inner join movMovement as m
                             on m.MovementID = wh.RunMovID
                         inner join dbo.genAddress as ga
                             on ga.AddressID = c.Consignor
                         inner join dbo.lstPostcode as lp
                             on lp.Postcode = ga.PostcodePrefix
                         inner join dbo.lstPostcodeRegion as lpr
                             on lpr.RegionID = lp.RegionID
                                and c.Cancelled = 0
                                and discrepancy.WhsHeaderID = wc.whsHeaderID
                     where wc.whsHeaderID = wh.whsHeaderID
                           and wc.StatusCode = 'NL'
                           and wh.ArrDepDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
                           and lpr.RegionID = <RegionID in your main query>
                     for xml path('')
                    ),1,1,''),'') as [Not Collected];
```

---

In response to comments below:

```
with cte as
(
    select lpr.RegionID
          ,lpr.Region
          ,sum(c.[Chargeable Weight]) as LeftOffWt
    from dbo.whsConsignment as wc
        inner join whsHeader as wh
            on wh.WhsHeaderID = wc.whsHeaderID
        inner join dbo.cgtConsignment as c
            on c.[Consignment Reference] = wc.ConsignmentReference
        inner join dbo.genAddress as ga
            on ga.AddressID = c.Consignor
        inner join dbo.lstPostcode as lp
            on lp.Postcode = ga.PostcodePrefix
        inner join dbo.lstPostcodeRegion as lpr
            on lpr.RegionID = lp.RegionID
                and c.Cancelled = 0
        where StatusCode in('NL')
            and wh.ArrDepDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
        group by lpr.RegionID
                ,lpr.Region
)
select cte.RegionID
    ,cte.Region
    ,cte.LeftOffWt
    ,isnull(stuff((select distinct ',' + coalesce(d.description,'NA')
                    from disConsignment as d
                        inner join whsHeader as wh
                            on wh.WhsHeaderID = d.WhsHeaderID
                        inner join whsConsignment as wc
                            on wc.whsHeaderID = wh.WhsHeaderID
                        inner join cgtConsignment as c
                            on c.[Consignment Reference] = wc.ConsignmentReference
                        inner join movMovement as m
                            on m.MovementID = wh.RunMovID
                        inner join dbo.genAddress as ga
                            on ga.AddressID = c.Consignor
                        inner join dbo.lstPostcode as lp
                            on lp.Postcode = ga.PostcodePrefix
                        inner join dbo.lstPostcodeRegion as lpr
                            on lpr.RegionID = lp.RegionID
                                and c.Cancelled = 0
                                and d.WhsHeaderID = wc.whsHeaderID
                    where wc.whsHeaderID = wh.whsHeaderID
                        and wc.StatusCode = 'NL'
                        and wh.ArrDepDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
                        and lpr.RegionID = cte.RegionID
                    for xml path('')
                    ),1,1,''),'') as [Not Collected]
from cte;
```

Comment: Hi @iamdave! this has been really helpful, thank you! However, I still get this error: Column 'lprdiscrepancy.RegionID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.  this is what I have replaced your suggestion with:                 and lpr.RegionID = lprdiscrepancy.RegionID

Comment: Then I have used lpr.RegionID = max(lprdiscrepancy.RegionID) but I don't think that is making any sense as the description is just a string of text.

Comment: it also takes 2 minutes to run (it's a relatively small query altogether) It's the inappropriate use of the aggregate that destroys the performance.

Comment: @Diana *Then I have used lpr.RegionID = max(lprdiscrepancy.RegionID)*  Don't just stab randomly at trying to fix your issue, actually try to understand what is happening in your query, what the error message means and as a result, what the necessary solution is and importantly *why* it works.  As you are not doing any aggregation within your sub-select and the error is stating that you need to be `group`ing or aggregating, this suggests your main query *is* aggregating.  Without your full query and table structure, we cannot help you further.

Comment: @iamdavid You are making a compelling point! Indeed my main query is aggregating. I have attached the whole query and you can see that I am using group by in my main query on lpr.RegionID.

Comment: @Diana  That query seems *way* complex for the output...  Do you really need all those `join`s?  Does the second script in my answer give you anything like your desired results?  Remember that you will need to terminate any statements before the `with` by putting a semi colon at the end of it.

Comment: I am confused by what you mean about the semi colon, can you please outline in my query when I need to make the change? Thank you!

Comment: @Diana  `with` needs to the first word in a query statement.  This means you cannot have something like `declare @StartDate date = '20170401'` before it unless you terminate that statement with a semi colon: `declare @StartDate date = '20170401';`.   To clarify, I am referring to the script I have added to my answer above, in response to your full script.